# Строковая константа

Tags: c

В строковой константе во внутреннем представлении строки в конце обязательно присутствует нулевой символ '\0', какой его можно увидеть?

В функции test в цикле условия i[s] != '\0', если убрать не равенство, результат получается одинаковый.

```
 void test(char i[]);

 main(){
   char i[] = "Hi!";
   test(i);
}

void test(char i[]){
 int s=0;
  while(i[s] != '\0'){
    printf("%d\n",s++);
 }
```

}

Comment: @avdoshkin

        если убрать не равенство, результат получается одинаковый

Правильно, почитайте про результат условных выражений. `i[s] != '\0'` и `i[s]` в условных выражениях идентичны.

Answer (score 3):

а вот так

```
void test(char i[]);

main(){
   char i[] = "Hi!";
   test(i);
}

void test(char i[]){
 int s=0;
  while(i[s] != '\0'){
    printf("%d - %d\n",i[s], s++);
 }
}
```

распечатает следующее

```
105 - 0
33 - 1
0 - 2
```

первое число - это код символа, а второе - его номер. В третьей строке как раз и видно нулевой символ.

P.S. Стиль кода - ужасный. Вообще то `i` - это обычно счетчики целого типа, `s` - строки. А у Вас все наоборот.

**upd**
исправил явные проблемы и добавил данных:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(char s[]) {
  int l = strlen(s);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
    printf("%c\t0x%x\t%d\n",s[i], s[i], i);
  };
}
int main(){
  char s[] = "Hi!";
  test(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Результат то не верный, еще одной буквы не хватает "H", вот по этому и запутался. 


    105 - i
    33 - !
    0 - '\0'

Comment: обновил ответ.
Но можно просто в оригинальном моем коде заменить `int s=0;` заменить на `int s=-1;` (как вариант).